# List all functions called from a particular function

Tags: gdb

I am looking for a command to list the functions which I have called from a particular function (not all function present in my code).

I tried `info functions`, but it lists down all the functions present in my code.

Comment: This is not a feature of GDB. You'll need a profiler.

Comment: ohh. ok... i was trying to debug using gdb.

Comment: gprof will do this, but only in total for a complete run of the program.